# Ionic 3 device information null

Tags: ionic3, uuid

I'm having a problem getting the UUID on certain devices, I still can not detect what it is due to.

The first thing to mention is that I'm using the plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/

On the other hand, I'm testing on real devices, not emulators or anything similar.

I am also trying to access the info within the platform.ready, I pass them an example code.

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

constructor(private device: Device){
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        console.log("this.device.uuid " + this.device.uuid);
        console.log("this.device.cordova " + this.device.cordova);
        console.log("this.device.model " + this.device.model);
        console.log("this.device.version " + this.device.version);
        console.log("this.device.serial " + this.device.serial);
    });
}
```

This happens in versions of Android before 7 (4.4+), in later versions I have no problem.